# Apache Shiro: Exception-Handling with Multiple Realms

Tags: authentication, shiro

We are using two realms (one for hashed passwords, the other one for generated plaintext keys) - this is working as expected.

With a single realm, we could throw a `DisabledAccountException` exception in our realm's `protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(final AuthenticationToken authToken)` and explicitly catch such an exception in our application.

Now that we have two realms, all exceptions are Shiro-internally caught; so if one realm fails, the second one can be tried as well. However, this kind of redirect will only throw generic `AuthenticationExceptions` to our application.

Is there any workaround with multiple realms so that we can have more specific exceptions (to know if an account is locked, the credentials are simply wrong,...)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify your own *AuthenticationStrategy* in your *ModularRealmAuthenticator*.
The *ModularRealmAuthenticator* uses *AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy* by default and *AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy* ignores the exceptions and keeps trying to login the users using all the realms available.

We had a similar scenario on the [tynamo](http://tynamo.org/) project and to workaround this issue I've implemented my own *AuthenticationStrategy*, called *FirstExceptionStrategy*, that works with multiple realms and throws the first exception it gets. This approach works fine as long as there is only **one *Realm* per *Token* type**.

The implementations is rather simple:

```
/**
 * {@link org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AuthenticationStrategy} implementation that throws the first exception it gets
 * and ignores all subsequent realms. If there is no exceptions it works as the {@link FirstSuccessfulStrategy}
 *
 * WARN: This approach works fine as long as there is ONLY ONE Realm per Token type.
 *
 */
public class FirstExceptionStrategy extends FirstSuccessfulStrategy {

    @Override
    public AuthenticationInfo afterAttempt(Realm realm, AuthenticationToken token, AuthenticationInfo singleRealmInfo, AuthenticationInfo aggregateInfo, Throwable t) throws AuthenticationException {
        if ((t != null) && (t instanceof AuthenticationException)) throw (AuthenticationException) t;
        return super.afterAttempt(realm, token, singleRealmInfo, aggregateInfo, t);
    }

}
```

I repeat, this **only** works if there is **ONLY ONE** Realm per Token type.

For more info about my particular scenario see here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/TYNAMO-154

Comment: Unfortunately we're using ``UsernamePasswordToken`` for both realms, so this won't solve our problem... But thanks for the input!

Comment: Without different _Tokens_ it will be really hard for the strategy to know if it should throw an exception or it should keep looking through the realm list. Take a look at _ModularRealmAuthenticator.doMultiRealmAuthentication_. Maybe you can create your own aggregate in _beforeAllAttempts_, save the exceptions in the aggregate in _afterAttempt_ and later throw the exception in _afterAllAttempts_.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I think that's not worth it. We are currently fine with the generic exception and will try your suggestion in case we need additional information.